# React - Dealing with undefined state when mapping over an array of objects from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

API data is fetched when component mounts, and state is set in the form

```
sectionData: {
  course: null,
  section_id: null,
  semester: null,
  number: null,
  seats: null,
  meetings: [],
  open_seats: null,
  waitlist: null,
  instructors: []
},
```

For reference the relevant API data looks like this

```
"meetings": [
 {
  "days": "TuTh",
  "room": "0324",
  "building": "IRB",
  "classtype": "",
  "start_time": "11:00am",
  "end_time": "12:15pm"
 },
 {
  "days": "MW",
  "room": "3120",
  "building": "CSI",
  "classtype": "Discussion",
  "start_time": "9:00am",
  "end_time": "9:50am"
 }
],
```

Using keys like course and section_id is fine, since they are predefined with null. However, if I am to map over each meeting object in meetings, and say access "days" or "room", each meeting is obviously undefined.

```
{this.state.sectionData.meetings.map(meeting => this.renderMeetings())}

    renderMeetings(meeting) {
        return (<div key={meeting}>     
            {meeting.days}
        </div>)
    }
```

Any easy fixes without having to make an entirely new Meeting component to predefine said keys? Merely checking for an undefined prevents React from crashing, but doesn't help with actually displaying the data.

Comment: what exactly so you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Am I unaware of all the capabilities of map.

In my limited experience the iterating variable `meeting` would be passed in to the function.

Would it help to Change

```
(meeting => this.renderMeetings())}
```

To This?

```
// pass meeting in to function
(meeting => this.renderMeetings(meeting))}
```

Comment: Right on. Really dumb mistake on my part. Was completely confused on why the lifecycle was acting up like this, and it turned out to be something so silly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your below code

```
renderMeetings(meeting) {
    return (<div key={meeting}>     
        {meeting.days}
    </div>)
}
```

`meeting` is an object so the key will always be converted to a string which is `[object Object]`. Keys can not be same